# Ruby on Rails Calendar using Table_Builder Month Change Not Functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I am trying to add a calendar to my rails app using [table_builder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars). I based my implementation off of their readme and this highly recommended [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars).

On the initial load, the calendar works beautifully. Each assignment is shown on the correct day. However, when the month is changed by clicking ">" or "<" which surround the month name, while the name of the month in the header is changed, the calendar itself is unchanged. Here is the block of code from my view that renders the calendar:

```
  <div id="calendar">  
  <h2 id="month">  
    <%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m-01") %>  
    <%= h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>  
    <%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m-01") %>  
  </h2>   
    <%= calendar_for(@assignments) do |calendar| %>
        <%= calendar.head('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') %>
        <% calendar.day(:day_method => :due_date) do |day, assignments| %>
            <%= day.day %>
            <ul>
                <% for assignment in assignments %>
                    <li>
                        <%= assignment.course.name %>: <%= link_to assignment.name, assignment_type_assignment_path(assignment.assignment_type, assignment)%>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

@assignments returns a complete list of all assignments associated with a given user. Each assignment as an attribute due_date which is the date we want the assignment to appear under in the calendar.

Here is the controller code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user = @current_user
        @assignments = @user.assignments
        @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
    end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, can you post some controller code?  Secondly, you are incrementing/decrementing `@date` by 1. Are you sure that `@date` is a `Date` object and not a `Time` or `DateTime` object?

Comment: Honestly, I copied that code from examples. It appears to me as if that would be set to today originally, then when ">" is clicked, the first of the next month should be passed as a param. How would that get passed though? Thanks

Comment: It's all in the controller and helpers, can you post the controller code you are using?

Comment: It is towards the end of the original post. I added it after you asked that earlier. Just the HomeController.

Comment: Is there other code that might be relevant? That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the current `@date` to the `calendar_for` helper, so it's simply defaulting to rendering the current (or some default) month.  You'll need to pass in `@date` like this:

```
calendar_for(@assignments, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month) do |calendar|
```